# ./configure error, on 32 bit ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, compile

I have Ubuntu 32 bit on i7 processor.
I tried to compile and install this package called xgrafix, I have installed dependencies, but now it has error as follow:

```
samir@samir-HP:~/Downloads/xgrafix$ ./configure --with-X11_LIBDIR /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: invalid host type: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/': machine `/usr/lib/i386' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/bash ./config/config.sub /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ failed
```

I have tried several thing but was unable to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just making a guess here.  Assuming that this particular `configure` script is written using make you might need to change

```
--with-X11_LIBDIR /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/  to

--with-X11_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/  (added the assignment operator)
```

Comment: Thanks... it worked.. i figured that out...   many many thanks... and if some one has compilation error related to Tcl/Tk, may be using latest version of source code would help.